# How to enable and disable onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

```
function my_function () {} (...)

// enabling onlick event
$("#link").prop("onclick", "my_function()");

// disabling onlick event
$("#some_button_click").click() {
    $("#link").prop("onclick", null);
}
```

I have a button that should disable an onlick event. That is fine.
But then, I need to reset the onclick event to the initial state, which is enable.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using jquery. so use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** and **[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** for 1.7+ or use **[bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** / **[unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)** for earlier versions.

```
  $("#link").on("click", my_function);


  // disabling onlick event
  $("#some_button_click").click(function(){
    $("#link").off("click");
  });
```

Also you do have some syntax issues in your current code pasted.

Comment: Wouldn't `off` destroy the event handler, so you'd have to re-hook it up to `my_function`? Not that that's a big deal to do in this case...

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes it will unbind the handler from the element, when needed it ca be bound again.